# Oracle Package having constant variables. How can we vary it based on clients

Tags: oracle, package

I have a package with two variables that has constant values like below.

```
person_name              CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (15)           := 'Adam';
person_city              CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (15)           := 'Houston';
```

This package variables are used across my database in stored procedures, other packages etc.

Now i want these variables to have values based on the client server who is calling. And i have all these maintained in a table like below

```
Server      Parameter       Value
Server1     person_name     Adam
Server1     person_city     Houston
Server2     person_name     Victor
Server2     person_city     Dallas
```

So when the package/SP is referenced/called from server1, i want my person_name and person_city to be defaulted to Adam and Houston. 
Similarly when the package/SP is referenced/called from server2, i want my person_name and person_city to be Victor and Dallas.

How can this be done? Is there anyway in oracle side, the client who is calling a particular SP or using a package variable? I wrote a function to get the value like below.

```
in package, 
person_name     CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (15)      :=GETPARAMVALUE(person_name);
person_city     CONSTANT VARCHAR2 (15)      :=GETPARAMVALUE(person_city);
```

and in the function, i will query the table

```
select * from parameterstable where parameter = (function's input) and servername = ????
```

How will i know the servername here?

Any help/tips will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Isn't this what a table is for?

Comment: this is an existing piece of code in the package and i cannot rewrite all the codes wherever this package is used. Is there anyway we can do with minimal effort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `server1` and `server2` are the client machines that are connecting to your server,

```
SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'HOST' )
```

should return the name of the client machine.  You can use that in your `GetParamValue` function to determine which row in the configuration table to read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should tell us what do you mean by 'Server'. Once we get it - we'll try to help.

At any case you should pay attention package variables are initialized once when the package is invoked so if it is possible the variables will be changed you have to refresh them in the package to not deal with incorrect values. So you need either retrieve them each time when you use them (in sp for instance) or add a trigger for update/insert in your settings table in order to refresh package variables properly.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sessio.htm

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I am assuming there must be some command that will re initialize the package again. Let me google on that. If you know, please tell me

Comment: It's impossible (at least I have no idea how to do it) to re-initialize package except invoke it again under new sessions.

Comment: I found it - DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE;

Comment: If the performance is crucial - try use DBMS_SESSION.REINITIALIZE

Comment: Unfortunately it seems there is no way to reset a package by name - only all of them...

Comment: :-( .Thanks Alexander. And i suppose the scope of a package variable is for a particular session. Please correct me if i am wrong. Wondering if i change the variable in this session for one app server, it would affect the value of other app servers too.

Comment: >>And i suppose the scope of a package variable is for a particular session.  - sure, it is.

Comment: @AlexanderTokarev by 'Server' he meant 'Server' as in the machine where the Database is Installed i.e. the Database Server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would help in identifying the server name-

```
SQL> select a.host_name,b.value from v$instance a, parameterstable b
     where a.host_name = b.server and b.parameter='person_name';

HOST_NAME      VALUE
---------   -----------
server1        Adam
```

Comment: I presume he should have additional grants on select to v$instance so SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'HOST' ) from Justin sounds more feasible.

Comment: Not really, I don't see a reason why he won't have access to `v$instance`. He can have similar access permissions issue with `SYS_CONTEXT` function.

Comment: Great! so you know if you have access to `SYS_CONTEXT` you have access to `v$instance` as well (just saying). Usually a lot of application features make use of these `sys` views, so its not usually a good idea to restrict `select` on them, and DBAs don't usually do that as well.

Comment: `v$instance` tells you what host the database server instances are running on (this will have multiple rows if you have a RAC cluster).  If you want to roll your own query, you would want to query `v$session`, specifically the `machine` column.  But then you'd need to figure out which of the many sessions are yours.  The simplest way to do that would be to use the `SESSIONID` attribute of the `USERENV` context, i.e. `select machine from v$session where audsid = sys_context( 'USERENV', 'SESSIONID' );`.  But there is no reason to do that when you can just get the `HOST` attribute.

Comment: Hmm, never really thought of how it would look in a RAC environment. Good information.